# Как правильно отобразить данные из @extends в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Такая вот проблема есть у меня файл layouts которые подключаю с помощью @extends() но вот отображаются эти файлы в обратном порядке. Данные второго файла показываются первыми а данные первого файла последними. Как с этим быть? Благодарю заранее     @extends('layouts.header')

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так добавьте в `header.blade.php` `@yield('content')`, а у этом файле, где выводите картинку и т.д напишите `@section('content') тут весь код из файла @endsection` **UPD**, скопируйте код как текст и добавьте еще содержимое файла `header.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

не наследуйтесь от headera, сделайте 1 главный шаблон в котором будет включен хедер и футер, и наследуйтесь от него всеми остальными файлами. К примеру

```
  <body>

        @include('header')

        @yield('content')

        @include('footer')

    </body>
```

и затем в каком либо другом наследуемом файле

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
  //ваш html код
@endsection`
```

Вот здесь можно прочитать об этом https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade